# Multiprocessing 'Pool' option deployed with python 3 on windowns 10 not working giving error

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing library for Python 3. The module is imported correctly and does not show any error, however when using it, I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

start_time = time.process_time()
p = Pool(10)

def print_range():
    for i in range(10000):
        print('Something')
end_time = time.process_time()
print(end_time-start_time)
p.map(print_range())
```

However I get this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Pool' from 'multiprocessing' (C: ...path file)

Has anyone encountered this error, and have a solution for it? Thanks

Comment: do you have a file called "multiprocessing.py" in the current working directory?

Comment: Not related to your current error, but you want to replace `map` with `apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be related to safely importing `main`. See [this section in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming). Specifically, you'd need to change your code like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def print_range():
    for i in range(10000):
        print('Something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.process_time()
    p = Pool(10)
    end_time = time.process_time()
    print(end_time-start_time)
    p.map(print_range()) # incorrect usage
```

In addition, your usage of `map()` is not correct. See the documentation for examples, or use `p.apply(print_range)` instead.

Comment: Yes, the error was the importing of main as well as p.map(), i replace as you suggested with p.apply and it worked! Thanks